# Highcharts/Highstock Scrollbar Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Our team is working on a proof of concept using the Highcharts/Highstock library. Everything is working perfectly, with the exception of adding vertical scrolling. I've added a fiddle and the accompanying code below. If you run the fiddler and scroll in the chart you'll see strange behavior...but, if you remove one row from the data set (i.e. "Test31"), it works fine. Any idea what's causing this? Are we missing an additional option somewhere? Thanks in advance!

(Note that this example is straight from the docs, all we did was add 30+ additional rows.)

https://jsfiddle.net/meppielmr/hywdwvzf/1/

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 320px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        marginLeft: 150
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Most popular ideas by April 2016'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api">UserVoice</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        tickLength: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1200,
        title: {
            text: 'Votes',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Votes',
        data: [
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117],
            ["Test1", 343],
            ["Test2", 343],
            ["Test3", 343],
            ["Test4", 343],
            ["Test5", 343],
            ["Test6", 343],
            ["Test7", 343],
            ["Test8", 343],
            ["Test9", 343],
            ["Test10", 343],
            ["Test11", 343],
            ["Test12", 343],
            ["Test13", 343],
            ["Test14", 343],
            ["Test15", 343],
            ["Test16", 343],
            ["Test17", 343],
            ["Test18", 343],
            ["Test19", 343],
            ["Test20", 343],
            ["Test21", 343],
            ["Test22", 343],
            ["Test23", 343],
            ["Test24", 343],
            ["Test25", 343],
            ["Test26", 343],
            ["Test27", 343],
            ["Test28", 343],
            ["Test29", 343],
            ["Test30", 343],
            ["Test31", 343]        
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Just to help understanding, example is drawn from: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/

Comment: It seems to be an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `cropThreshold`. This should have been made clear somewhere in DOCS, as it is not intuitive to check this in my opinion.

[From API on plotOptions.bar.cropThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.cropThreshold):

> When the series contains less points than the crop threshold, all points are drawn, event if the points fall outside the visible plot area at the current zoom. The advantage of drawing all points (including markers and columns), is that animation is performed on updates. On the other hand, when the series contains more points than the crop threshold, the series data is cropped to only contain points that fall within the plot area. The advantage of cropping away invisible points is to increase performance on large series.
>
> Defaults to **50**.

So setting `cropThreshold` to some arbitrary large number we get a working graph.

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    cropThreshold: 1000
  }
},
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/hywdwvzf/3/

Comment: I must have overlooked this when reading the docs. Agreed though, this option should at the very least be present in their example. Thanks for the quick response, much appreciated!

Comment: @ewolden I have  commented  cropThreshold: 1000 line and tried to play with scoller but this line does not affect on scroller tried in same example you have given

Comment: @VishalPachpande This was not a fix for removing the scrollbar. If you set `cropThreshold: 10` and try to scroll far down you will see some strange behaviour. That is what this was intended to fix.